# Знаки вопроса вместо текста

Tags: php

Знаю, уже задавал вопрос, но уже все перепробовал постоянно выводит?
так сделал:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
```

Не помогла, помогите, пожалуйста.

**Дополнено.**

Ввод сообщения:

```
<?php

mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
$sql  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' ");
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$date = date("H:i:s");
if ($row['ban'] < 1) {
    if ($row['level'] > 0) {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    } else {
        $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    }
    if (strlen($message) > 250 || strlen($message) < 1) {
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (username,message,time,color_chat) values('" . $_SESSION['username'] . "','$message','$date','" . $row['color_chat'] . "')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

вывод:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<br><font color='Greenyellow'>" . $row['time'] . "</font> <font color='" . $row['color_chat'] . "'><b>" . $row['username'] . "</b></font>: " . $row['message'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в настройках базы данных и таблицы, из которой забираете строки, какая там кодировка, такую и напишите в ("set charset '$incoding'")

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно: `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");` 
Если не поможет, то код в студию.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: В таком случае, если пропишите mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); то должно всё заработать. Только забивать и выводить нужно с этой строкой

Comment: А еще стоит попробовать `SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'` это не то же самое, что `SET NAMES`...